# Can I run planning on different solvers of the same project at a time?

Tags: optaplanner

This happens intermittently and I don't see pattern on it. My scenario is that I programmatically create 7 solvers and after creating each solver, I send it to planning.

What happens sometimes is only 1 or 2 solvers are solving it. Sometimes, 5 solvers don't even seem to receive the request body because the `best-solution` property is null and on solvers that successfully solved, it wasn't null.

```
{
  "container-id": "spread-TVF_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT",
  "solver-id": "2020-02-11-solver",
  "solver-config-file": "bookingSolveConf.solver.xml",
  "status": "SOLVING",
  "score": {
    "value": null,
    "scoreClass": null
  },
  "best-solution": null
}
```

The error that I receive from REST API is the one I wrote in the title. `Unknown error updating solver state.` And I can find traces of exception on the cmd logs like these:

```
07:03:39,300 INFO  [org.kie.server.services.optaplanner.SolverServiceBase] (default task-36) Solver '2020-02-11-solver' successfully created in container 'spread-TVF_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
07:03:39,978 ERROR [org.kie.server.services.optaplanner.SolverServiceBase] (default task-36) Error retrieving solver '2020-02-11-solver' state from container 'spread-TVF_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT': java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.kie.server.services.optaplanner.SolverServiceBase$$Lambda$1575/1257579546@24f02075 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5c8f3f9e[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 7]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2080)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:832)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1365)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.kie.server.services.optaplanner.SolverServiceBase.solvePlanningProblem(SolverServiceBase.java:489)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.kie.server.services.optaplanner.SolverServiceBase.solvePlanningProblem(SolverServiceBase.java:219)
        at deployment.kie-server.war//org.kie.server.remote.rest.optaplanner.SolverResource.solvePlanningProblem(SolverResource.java:294)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor164.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:517)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:406)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:370)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:355)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:372)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:344)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:317)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:355)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:227)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.7.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
        at javax.servlet.api@1.0.0.Final//javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@17.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.21.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

To my basic understanding of the exception, does that mean I am limited to executing only one planning at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can run multiple `Solver` instances from the same (or different) `SolverFactory` at the same time.** Many users do this, especially in multi-tenant environments. In fact, `SolverFactory` was designed with this in mind: `SolverFactory` is thread-safe. Note that a `Solver` isn't.

Starting from optaplanner 7.32.0.Final, just use `SolverManager` (docs chapter merged for the 7.33 release, didn't make 7.32):

```
// all these methods return immediately: the solving happens on a separate thread.
solverManager.solve(problem1, this::saveSolution);
solverManager.solve(problem2, this::saveSolution);
solverManager.solve(problem3, this::saveSolution);
```

With our without the quarkus (coming soon) or [spring-boot (released)](https://github.com/spring-guides/getting-started-guides/pull/126) integration to inject that SolverManager for you.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was using the workbench described here https://docs.optaplanner.org/7.29.0.Final/optaplanner-wb-es-docs/html_single

Comment: We might not support that there, not sure.